# Dictionary containing Int array – getting value for key and index

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, syntax

I'd like to create a dictionary that maps an `Int` onto an array of `Int`s. Using the structure `var myDictionary = [Int:[Int]]()` seems to work fine when I'm adding values to it. But I'm having trouble retrieving values for a key and index. I'm doing `myDictionary[key][index]`, but it doesn't seem to work. I get the error

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[(Int)]?' with an index of type 'Int'

Can you please explain me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you subscript a `Dictionary` with a key you get an optional value back (in this case `[Int]?`). If you want to subscript this array you have to use optional chaining since optionals don't have this subscript:

```
let optionalElement: Int? = myDictionary[key]?[index]
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir! will accept your answer as soon as I can